# Socket Programming with ACE c++

Tags: c++, ace

I am new to the ACE framework.. and i'm looking to explore the socket programming using ACE. I found the doxygen documentation - 
http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/5.7.6/html/ace/a00614.html#aced00dccf394509a056ce4bccaf40b24

and it is no doubt helpful, but i was looking for some advanced examples of code to get a better understanding. If anyone can help me with it.

Comment: The ACE downloads should include some sample applications for you to peruse.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to buy some of the ACE books, see https://www.remedy.nl/opensource/ace.html for some resources, in the sidebar on the right the 4 ACE books are listed

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout the *examples* and *tests* directory which comes with the ace distribution. The examples and tests demonstrate plenty of features from basic to advanced, and some of them are sort of tutorials.

The books are also good but as they take you through the framework in a step wise fashion, but you must purchase them. In the mean time - the examples and tests are freely available for you to study and learn.

When I was trying to learn ACE framework (As I started learning C++ with ACE only) - I spent most of my time in those 2 directories and little by little, I was able to answer all of my questions.